# TYPO3 insert plugin on every pages

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 version 7.6.18. I want to insert some plugin in every pages, I think it may be do with typoscript? Help me please, how to do it ?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085019/typo3-how-do-i-insert-page-content-into-template

Comment: I need insert exactly plugin )

Comment: That is not a duplicate question Heinz. Here we talk about a plugin.. There they talk about just content.. could be just a partial... Good Question Mikael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to insert a specific plugin on every page, you can simply add it to your page like so:

```
page = PAGE
page{
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10{
        # the fluid template settings
    }
    # add a fixed plugin to be rendered after the normal fluid template
    20 = USER
    20{
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        extensionName = MyExt
        vendorName = MyVendor
        pluginName = Pi1
        switchableControllerActions{
            TheController{
                0 = actionName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This basically adds a new section to your page rendering that only renders your plugin.

Comment: With TYPO3 8.7 this result in error:
$className "\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap" must not start with a backslash.
Solution is to remove the leading \

Comment: It works for me, but there must be another method to add it within `FLUIDTEMPLATE` and not at the end of the page.

Comment: Instead of page.20 you can move it to page.10.variables.somevariable and then render it inside your fluid template like every other variable

Answer (score 0):

You could also load the plugin into `lib` and render it in your FLUID template.

**TypoScript**

```
lib.myPlugin = USER
lib.myPlugin {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = MyExt
    vendorName = MyVendor
    pluginName = Pi1
    switchableControllerActions{
        TheController{
            0 = actionName
        }
    }
}
```

**FLUID template**

```xml
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.myPlugin"/>
```