# Typo3 create reference element for all subpages

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I have a TYPO3 8.7.

I need an element (plugin) to be displayed for all subpages.
I found such solutions:

1) [Create element reference](http://www.typo3manual.com/old-versions/typo3-manual-6/6-create-reference/61-creating-a-reference-element/) But I do not know how to add it simply on all pages?

2) [Add plugin on every pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858283/typo3-insert-plugin-on-every-pages) But is it possible to copy exactly my plugin installed on the page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches are suboptimal, since you either had to create a reference content record on each page or your plugin would not be configured manually anymore.

My recommendation would be to put that particular plugin into a specific column of the root page and inherit the content of that column via the "slide" feature of the CONTENT cObject:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html#slide

We are using this feature i.e. for the whole footer section of https://coders.care including the twitter plugin and the random testimonial content.